# SVG to canvas Image working half of the time

Tags: javascript, svg, drawimage

I want to compare two svg paths (user and model) at some point. The idea is to transform each of them onto ImageData to be able to make pixel comparisons. The problem I have is using the drawImage which leads me to an empty canvas half of the time.

```js
let modelCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let modelContext = modelCanvas.getContext("2d");
modelCanvas.width = 898;
    modelCanvas.height = 509;
document.body.appendChild(modelCanvas);
let modelImg = new Image(898, 509);
modelImg.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBjbGFzcz0ic3ZnLW[....]';
modelContext.drawImage(modelImg, 0, 0, 898, 509);
```

The code is pretty straightforward and always run without producing error. Still drawImage seems to fail silently times to times.

Here is the JSFiddle (with the full data string) :
https://jsfiddle.net/Ldgpuo03/

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try `modelImg.onload = function() {modelContext.drawImage(modelImg, 0, 0, 898, 509);}`

Comment: Thank you very much, I was struggling here !
However I don't really get from where the problem is coming from : the btoa method does not seems being asynchronous : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/D%C3%A9coder_encoder_en_base64.

Do you have extra information on this fix?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image loading by web browser is an asynchronous operation.

You are trying to call `modelContext.drawImage` when the image is not guaranteed to be loaded.

You must place your drawing code inside the [`image.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) callback function

This function will be called once when the image loading is fully finished.

```js
let modelCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let modelContext = modelCanvas.getContext("2d");
modelCanvas.width = 40;
modelCanvas.height = 40;
document.body.appendChild(modelCanvas);

let modelImg = new Image();
modelImg.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK1my.png?s=48';
modelImg.onload = function(){
  modelContext.drawImage(modelImg, 0, 0, 40, 40);
}
```